# For what function is the multiplicative derivative equal to itself?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The multiplicative derivative is defined as $f^*(x) = e^\frac{{f^{'}(x)}}{f(x)}$. What is the solution to $f(x) = e^\frac{f^{'}(x)}{f(x)}$ apart from the trivial $f(x) =1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
f(x) &=& e^\frac{f^{'}(x)}{f(x)} \\
\ln f(x) &=& \dfrac{f^{'}(x)}{f(x)} \\
f(x) \ln f(x) &=& f'(x) \\
\dfrac{\mathrm dx}{\mathrm df} &=& \dfrac{1}{f \ln f} \\
x &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm df}{f \ln f} \\
x &=& \displaystyle \int \dfrac{\mathrm d(\ln f)}{\ln f} \\
x &=& \ln \ln f +C \\
f &=& e^{e^{x-C}} \\
\end{array}$$

Comment: Your method is only valid, if there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=1$.